# why do these two outputs differ?

Tags: c++, c++17

Whether I use scanf instead of cin with the same number (999999999.1) the outcomes differ.
Why?

```
// code 1 
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
int main() {
    double n; 
    cin >> n;  
    printf("%f\n",ceil(n));  
    cout << ceil(n); 
}
```

```
// code 2
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
int main() {
    double n; 
    scanf("%f",&n); 
    printf("%f\n",ceil(n));  
    cout << ceil(n); 
}
```

Comment: Most compilers will warn about wrong scanf and printf conversions. Compile with a high warning level (-Wall or /W4 etc.) and carefully read, try to fully understand and and fix every warning. (It's tedious because 90% of the warnings don't matter but the 10% may bite you.)

Answer (score 2):

```
    scanf("%f",&n);
```

is wrong. `%f` is for reading `float`. You should use `%lf` to read `double`.

(Printing of `double` can be done via `%f`)

Comment: What does it happen if I insert %f to read a double?

Comment: Mismatch in format specifier and data invokes *undefined behavior*. It allows anything to happen.

Comment: and internally?

Comment: @fabiocs UB makes no distinction with internal and external.

Comment: what do you mean by UB?

Comment: @fabiocs It's acronym for Undefined Behaviour. See MikeCAT's earlier comment.

Comment: My final question is why is it possible to read a double using %lf as format specifier and it's possible to print out analogously to floating point data values?

Comment: It's pretty clear what typically happens, and you (Mike) are knowledgeable enough to answer it. Simply saying "UB" and shrug is ... unsatisfying.

Comment: due to parameter promotions that happen in a variadic function, `float` is promoted to `double` so `%f` and `%lf` can both be used since the function only ever received a double and never a float. When you read you pass a pointer and there there is a difference between `float*` and `double*`.

Comment: where is this difference?